# Capybara path helpers throwing ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm using rspec-rails 2.13.1 and Capybara 1.1.4. Whenever I try to `get root_path` or `get page_path("anything")`, the spec throws `ActionController::RoutingError:No route matches [GET] "/"`

I can run `visit 'http://example.dev` no problem, but I'd much rather use URL helpers.  Any idea why this might not be working?

Comment: Do you define root in the routes, like root :to => "home#index"

Comment: Yes, and Billy Chan's answer below helped me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use named urls in Capybara like

```
visit root_path
```

But you can't use `get`, `post` in Capybara, which are better for controller tests. Also, they are considered low level in Capybara's integration tests.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes it's difficult to know where to draw the line in integration tests vs controller tests.  I suppose the `response.status should be(200)` sort of tests should be in the controller specs as well?

Comment: @professormeowingtons, yes, what you said belongs to controller specs. The rule of thumb to differentiate them is, integration test will mimic what human being could do while controller tests are for machine. For example, human being can't POST, PUT, but machine can.